# Passing function arguments from one function to another, without actually typing them (PHP)

Tags: php, parameters, reference, arguments

I was wondering if it is possible to pass function arguments without actually rewriting them.

```
<?php

class example()
{
    __construct()
    {
        a("hello", "second_param", "another"); // <--- CALL
    }

    function a($param1, $param2, $param3) // <--- PARAMS
    {
        // call b(), passing this function its parameters
        b( $SOME_NEAT_TRICK_TO_GET_ARGS ) // <--- I WANT TO BE LAZY HERE AND GET ALL THE PASSED PARAMS

        // do something
    }

    function b( $SOME_NEAT_TRICK_TO_GET_ARGS ) // <--- I WANT TO BE LAZY HERE AND JUST PASS THE PARAMS ALONG
    {
        var_dump($param1); // <--- I WANT TO READ THEM HERE
        var_dump($param2);
        var_dump($param3);

        // do something
    }
}
```

I'd like to pass the parameters in an array in the same order.

Comment: Define your params as an array instead

Comment: If the three values are conceptually and semantically linked in some way, define an object or data structure to hold them.  Then pass that one object to the functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing is to use an array for the second function parameter. Will looks like this:

```
function a () { // As much elements as you want can be passed here (or you can define it fix)
    b(func_get_args());
}


function b ($arr) {
    die(var_dump($arr)); // You have all elements from the call of a() here in their passed order ([0] => ..., [1] => ..., ...)
}
```